# get the contact information on lead convert into account email template

Tags: workflow, email-template, account

I have created a workflow rule that works fine when an lead is converted into account. It sends an email towards a specific sales agent but without the full data needed.

Email template example:

```
Account Name: Women Voice Network 
Website: www.womenvoicenetwork.com 
*Contact Name: [data missing]
Contact Email: [data missing]
Phone: [data missing]
```

I don't know how to sync the contact information with the account information in the email template.
My goal is when a lead is converted to send a full information towards the sales agents.

[image]

Going more into details:
I have email template ready with the following information:

```
Account Name: {!Account.Name} 
Website: {!Account.Website} 
Contact Name: {!Contact.Name} 
Contact Email: {!Contact.Email} 
Phone: {!Contact.Phone}
```

Then I have created a workflow upon account creation to send that email to a specific user.

Then i have a full lead prepared with info needed from the email template and upon converting the last 3 rows are missing as described above.

Please advise,

Darko

Comment: do you see data on the converted Account and Contact records?

Comment: yes the lead has full value data and upon conversion the name, phone and email goes to contact company goes to account and so on. So when I pull the information from email template i can't get the values from the contact. only from the account.

Comment: I assume you are trying to find contact fields from select Fields? the same scenario is working just fine for me. i recreated in my sandbox and it is working fine for preview. I'm going to convert lead and see what happens.

Comment: @naruto-sfdc see the update of the question if that helps.

Comment: I was able to recreate the issue, looks like a bug not sure if it is Working As Designed in salesforce terms. One work around is since these fields are mapped to Account and Contact fields, you could use Lead fields in the template.

`Account Name: {!Lead.Company} 
Website: {!Lead.Website} 
Contact Name: {!Lead.Name} 
Contact Email: {!Lead.Email} 
Phone: {!Lead.Phone}`

Comment: @naruto-sfdc this doesn't work. I found a workaround I will post it soon. Thank you so much for your time and effort, I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I found a workaround of this issue that I had it for some time.

Instead of creating a workflow for the account object I created a workflow for the Lead object and I added the following criteria:

**Evaluation Criteria**

Every time lead is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria.

**Rule Criteria**

Lead:converted equal to true.

And in the Email Template I am keeping the same fields as above.

```
Account Name: {!Account.Name} 
Website: {!Account.Website} 
Contact Name: {!Contact.Name} 
Contact Email: {!Contact.Email} 
Phone: {!Contact.Phone}
```

This way every time a lead is converted it will activate the workflow rule and send an email towards the sales with the information mentioned in the email template.

Kind Regards,

Darko